# set the height of a box with JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, height

I want to change the height of a box that has id # block2, I will change it according to the user's browser window, if the window length is 1000px then the box height will be 1000px.

**I'll check the size of the browser window each time it's resized**

```
var winHeight = $(window).height(),
    winWidth = $(window).width();

$(window).resize(function(){    
    $('#block2').css("height",winWidth + "px");
    console.log($('#block2').height())
});
```

if something is wrong please correct it .. because the code I wrote doesn't work in the browser

Comment: and how to view the height of an html element in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the height of the element using jquery by:

```
$('#yourelementid').css('height');
```

also compute windows width, height in `resize` event then try applying.

Check this demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


$(window).resize(function() {    
var winHeight = $(window).height();
var winWidth = $(window).width();
$('#block2').css("height", winWidth + "px");
     alert($('#block2').css('height'));
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block2" style"border:1px solid black">
<p>content</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $win = $(window);
```

You can get element height and width using

`$win.height()` and `$win.width()`

You can set the height of your element by

```
 $("#yourEelementID").height('Your value');
```

In Your Case,

```
$win.on('resize',function(){
$("#block2").height($win.width());
console.log($('#block2').height());});
```

Check current element height using,

```
console.log($('#block2').height());
```